# Java program infinite loop in sum of even integers

Tags: java, numbers, calculation

I am creating a program that prints the sum of the even numbers from a range of 0 to the number that the user entered. For example, if the user entered the number 20, the program would calculate the sum of all of the even numbers between 0 and 20.

When I tested the program out with the number 10, it worked. But I tried using a different number, 35, and it was just stuck in an infinite loop. I would appreciate any and all help. The code will be posted below:

(Edit) Thanks for the feedback everyone! After talking with a friend, we realized that the solution is actually pretty simple. We were just making it complicated. Still, thanks for all of the suggestions.

```
//**************************************************************
 // Prints the sum of the even numbers within a range of 0
 // and the integer that the user enters.
 //
 // @me
 // @version_1.0_11.7.17
 //**************************************************************
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenNumbersSum
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int user_num = 2;   // variable that stores the user's number
        int sum;    // stores the sum of the needed values

        System.out.print("Enter an integer greater than or equal to, 2: "); // prompt user for input
        user_num = input.nextInt();

        // checks to see if the value entered is valid or not.
        while (user_num < 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry. Must enter an integer greater than or equal to, 2.\n");
            System.out.print("Enter an integer greater than or equal to, 2: ");
            user_num = input.nextInt();
        }

        // starts adding the values
        for (sum = 0; sum <= user_num;)
        {
            if (user_num % 2 == 0)  // checks if the number is even
                sum+=user_num;  // add the number to sum
            else
                continue;  // I thought that I might need this, but ended up changing nothing.
        }

        System.out.println();   // extra line for cleanliness
        System.out.printf("The sum of the even numbers between 0 and %d is %d.", user_num, sum);    // prints the result
    }
}
```

Comment: user_num doesn't change within your for loop. You should accept input again.

Comment: Why are you comparing `sum` to `user_num` in a for loop with only 2 terms?

Comment: `for (sum = 0; sum <= user_num;)` doesn't make sense, don't you want to loop `user_num` times? Then you'd use that value to determine if the number should be summed or not

Comment: After looking over my code, I just realized what the program is actually doing. I'm basically just doubling any even numbers. I'm gonna try everyone's ideas, along with a few of my own and give an update later. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing loop for this, there are efficient way to do it.

```
Sum of numbers between 1-N = (N(N+1))/2

Sum of even numbers between 1-N = (N(N+2))/4
```

where N = user given input number till which you would like to add even numbers

**NOTE:** you can add validation on input number that it’s even by (n%2 == 0) and return error if it’s not

Answer (score 0):

The variable you have used in condition (i.e. *sum* & *user_num*) no one changes in case of odd number and your code stuck in never-ending loop.
You should use counter variable ( e.g. **i** from 1 to user_num) and use that number in the condition. Example:

```
    // starts adding the values
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= user_num; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)  // checks if the number is even
            sum+=i;  // add the number to sum
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should be like this.

```
int total_sum = 0; 
for (int sum = 0; sum <= user_num; sum++)
        {
            if (sum % 2 == 0)  // checks if the number is even
                total_sum+=sum;  // add the number to total sum
            else
                continue;  // I thought that I might need this, but ended up changing nothing.
        }
// note print total sum
System.out.println(totalsum);
```

your initial program just kept on checking entered number is even or odd.
And the entered number to sum.
So sum was always double of the entered number is even.
If entered number is odd it would go to infinite loop as entered_num(odd) % 2 == 0 always false and execute else statement.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I just realized what my code is doing a few minutes ago. I guess I was just caught up in the moment and wasn't thinking. I'll try to fix it and give an update!